# How can I build my Gradle project using a Windows JDK from Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, bash, gradle, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Windows 10 machine recently forcibly upgraded me to the new "Creators Update" version of windows, the "About your PC" widget now reports my OS version as "1703".

I thought I would have a crack at using the Windows Subsystem for Linux / Ubuntu on Windows to compile my Gradle projects.

I have a Windows JDK installed at `c:\jvm\jdk1.8.0_102`.

In my MinGW terminal window ("git bash"), I can setup a JAVA_HOME and execute the gradle wrapper script from my source directory and it will just work:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/c/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102
./gradlew tasks
```

But I can't figure out how to do an equivalent thing with WSL.
Opening up the "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" terminal, changing to my source directory and invoking the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102
./gradlew tasks
```

Results in the following:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /mnt/c/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Note that the Windows JDK runs fine from within the bash terminal.  Executing `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java.exe -version` in the Ubuntu terminal will work fine.

**The question is**:

Is there any way to run my gradlew script from a "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" terminal using the Windows JDK I've previously installed.

*Please note*:

I'm specifically asking if it's possible to get my Gradle script running using the Windows JDK, not an Ubuntu/Linux JDK installed with WSL.
I understand I can likely run my gradle wrapper script by installing a Linux JDK within the Windows Sunbsystem for Linux, but I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to run my builds using the Windows JDK.

Comment: Hello @Shorn, I am curious whether you have managed to set up your environment to use Gradle scripts in WSL without having it install into Linux.

Comment: @MartinD No, I gave up after failing to find much info out there for this kind of thing.  Decided to give the WSL a few years to bake - MinGW/Cygwin etc. are fine for my usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you launch `./gradlew` from inside WSL, it attempts to run the Java binary from `$JAVA_HOME` Java installation. What kind of installation is it? Does it contain Windows binary or Linux binary?

If the question is reduced to: "how to run a windows binary from WSL".

Then the answer is: "you can't - that's not supported".

- https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/333
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2140

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure I didn't miss anything obvious, I downloaded Android Studio (which contains JDK, or rather, minimal set of Java tools to build Android projects) for Windows and Linux and installed them to 2 different directories: Windows version in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio` and Linux version in `~/android-studio`.

Inside WSL, I first set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre` and ran `gradlew`. It gave me `invalid directory` error message.

Next, I set `JAVA_HOME` to `~/android-studio/jre`. Everything worked as expected.

And then I copied Android Studio for Windows to `~/android-studio-windows` and set `JAVA_HOME` to `~/android-studio-windows/jre`. It gave me the same `invalid directory` error message, so I think WSL isn't able to use Windows tools as they are (well, at least not for the moment).

So, if your goal is to use gradle in WSL, I think you need to install OpenJDK for Linux (or something similar) inside WSL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **WSL** and you want to run **gradlew from WSL terminal** then you can do it as follow:

```sh
cmd.exe /c gradlew --version
cmd.exe /c gradlew :help
cmd.exe /c gradlew app:dependencies
cmd.exe /c gradlew app:dependencies | grep -i "com.android.support"
```

**I'm using windows version:**

```
rdey@surface-book:/mnt/c/Users/rdey/git/ici$ cmd.exe /c "systeminfo" | grep "^OS Version"
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
```